# Division on ARM

Tags: arm

When performing division on ARM, this is the code snippet that I encountered.

```
   0x83d8 <main+12>:    mov r3, #10
   0x83dc <main+16>:    str r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x83e0 <main+20>:    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
=> 0x83e4 <main+24>:    ldr r2, [pc, #40]   ;; 0x8414 <main+72>
   0x83e8 <main+28>:    smull   r1, r2, r2, r3
   0x83ec <main+32>:    asr r3, r3, #31
   0x83f0 <main+36>:    rsb r3, r3, r2
   0x83f4 <main+40>:    str r3, [r11, #-8]
```

In the original program, I store the value `10` to a variable, divide it by `3` and store it in the same variable.

`[r11, #-8]` in the above example has the value `0xa`. After `0x83e4`, r2 is loaded up as `0x55555556`. My doubts are as follows :-

1. Is this a common way of performing division without the `div` instruction?
2. What are the other ways you have encountered in which division is performed without using an instruction that performs division?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing compilers will typically use the method above for compiling division by a constant.

You can read more about it at the following links:

- [Integer division by constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114090130/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2005/12/12/502980.aspx)
- [How can I reverse optimized integer division/modulo by constant operations?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-can-i-reverse-optimized-integer-division-modulo-by-constant-operations)
- [Compiler tricks in x86 assembly](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=115)